# Share session between domains on the same server

Tags: php, security, session, cookies, cross-domain

I have a single server with two domains. I use the same SESSION ID (Let's imagine you manually change the cookie value of "PHPSESSID" on both servers, or using session_id(...) before session_start).
The session file used by the two domains is the same, I verified it on the disk.

What happens is that the session is cleared when I change the domain. I mean cleared for BOTH domains and WITHOUT writing anything to the session.

Take note that this worked some weeks ago on the same server, and nothing has changed (at least we didn't manually change/upgrade anything)

The scripts I'm using to debug are these, identical on each server:

SET session:

```
<?
session_id(PUT_HERE_THE_SAME_SESSION_ID);
session_start();
$_SESSION['KEY'] = 'VALUE';
?>
```

CHECK session:

```
<?
session_start();
echo "SESSION ID: ".session_id()."<br>\n";
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

THE MAGICAL BEHAVIOUR:
SET session on A
CHECK session on A, everything is ok
refresh, wait or what else on A, then CHECK, ok
check session on B -> EMPTY
check again on A -> EMPTY!!!!!

The same behaviour if you swap A and B.

Any good suggestion is appreciated.
I don't want another way to do this, I need to understand what's going on.

Comment: Sessions can't be shared between different "domains", far as I know. It's a security issue.

Comment: And how do you know it? Is there any documentation? 
I had it working!!

Comment: As far as I know, the sessions are stored in files and there is a huge unique folder for them. The data is serialized but not encrypted with a different key for every website.

Comment: You "had" it working; ok. So now it doesn't? (*wondering why I received an Upvote*)

Comment: I verified that the session file is the same for both domains, so it can be protected only if there is a mechanism inside PHP to associate data to a single domain and not to another. Any notice of this?

Comment: I can surprise a lot of "upvoters" with things they can't imagine can be made in PHP ;)

Comment: I could spend a lot of time Googling this and you could very well be right that you can share sessions with different domains on the "same" machine, but I honestly don't have time. In the real world, if sessions were interchangeable between domains, that would prove to be a huge security risk.

Comment: Remember that to steal a user session requires only to know your SSID, and this can be done with a simple packet sniffing (in non https context, I mean).

Comment: I think that in shared hosting the best practice is to configure the single hosts to have separate folders for session files, security issue solved ;)

Comment: Ah yes, you are right indeed Ludovico.

Comment: I just verified that the same data saved in session from different domains is not the same, and the data saved by a domain cannot be decoded (with session_decode) by the other one. This means a different encription key for every domain (how the heck I did it before?)

Comment: That's when a working copy comes in handy ;-)

Comment: http://websec.io/2012/09/10/Encrypted-Sessions-with-PHP.html "PHP takes the values in your sessions and serializes them to be put in a text file in the session.save_path for your application. This [...] could be a major issue is there's something you need to protect. It's even worse on a shared hosting environment (as was mentioned in another post) where anyone running under the same web server user can potentially access your session files...or even inject content into them, bypassing security restrictions completely." SO WHAT?????? I'm confused.

Comment: Last: here http://websec.io/2012/08/24/Shared-Hosting-PHP-Session-Security.html says exactly that is possible to share a session between websites on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible but is prevented by suhosin that, in default configuration, encrypts session data using the document root as a key.
For this reason sessions of different domains cannot be shared in this way.